# Why does a comma work inside a console.log and not alert?

Tags: javascript

I have seen some code examples using a comma inside a console.log and I thought when combining strings and variables you need the + operator. Could you explain the difference?

```
console.log("my list items", myListItems[0]);
alert("my list items" + myListItems[0]);
```

Comment: [`console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/log) but [`window.alert(message);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert` function does only support one [argument (message)](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/alert):

> window.alert(message);

`console.log` function support multiple [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

> console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
>   console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]);

Answer (score 5):

A comma separates the arguments in a function call.

`console.log` is designed to accept multiple arguments.

`alert` is designed to accept exactly one argument.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log` supports any number of arguments. `alert` only accepts 1.

There is a subtle difference is that `console.log` (and its siblings) will do an equivalent of `Array.from(arguments).join(' ')` so that there is a space between the arguments.